# Dealing with an invalid edit

Tags: support, edits

[Revision in question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16901590/2)

This editor took my correct answer, and turned it into an incorrect one. This led to negative comments, and even a downvote before I was able to roll it back and explain what happened.

Besides the rollback, is there anything that can be done to prevent this happening again? I ask this mainly out of curiousity, since this does have potential to sabotage other people's answers.

Comment: Not really no. If the user is particularly abusive you could flag.

Comment: You can also @mention the editor and explain why you rolled back. This may change the editor's behaviour in the future

Comment: That's just the nature of group-edit. I'd roll-back and leave a comment to the editor just in case.

Answer (score 7):

If they continue rolling back your rollback you could flag, but in this particular case it looks like it's just a simple mistake, not malicious or abusive behavior.  Given that, rolling back the edit as you've done should be fine.  If you want you could post a comment on your answer explaining the reason you rolled it back and giving the editor an opportunity to explain their decision or at least understand their mistake.  (Note that you can reply to an editor using the @ functionality.  Even though it won't auto-complete their name it will notify them if you type it out.)

Comment: Yeah, I knew this one was a mistake and not malicious, but it just had me curious as to "what if it were", what can I do about it. Thanks for letting me know about the @ thing - I didn't know it would still notify them even if they hadn't already posted.