# There should be an option to make the answers 'uneditable'

Tags: feature-request, edits, locked

.. or at least let me preview all suggestions first.

On one of the Stack Exchange sites I had a perfectly good answer, and somebody edited it so that it contained broken English and wrong answers. I don't care how much reputation the editor has, the OP should have the final say as to whether the edit is appropriate or not.

Or the OP should have the option of 'locking' his answer so that others cannot edit it, perhaps as an overall setting in their profile. I suppose it could be a matter of preference. Some people are much more diligent in their writing than others.

Comment: You can rollback at anytime. Did you know that?

Comment: Can we see the answer that you feel was edited incorrectly?

Comment: See "Voting is different on meta":  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: Votes mean agreement/disagreement on meta, not question quality

Comment: Privileging the poster to have any suggestions wait for him is a bad idea. He might not come.

Comment: Didn't know about the 'rollback' feature. Thanks @Jan.

Comment: Since you're not going to get this feature, see how you can [deal with invalid edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182837/147655).

Answer (score 17):

In these cases, it's better to:

- Rollback the edit (click "Edit", then "Rollback" to the appropriate revision)
- Flag the answer and ask a moderator to step in

Stack Overflow is collaboratively edited; it doesn't make sense to kill the very feature that sets us apart from the forums.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [points that George Stocker makes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186339/176080)

> Or the OP should have the option of 'locking' his answer so that others cannot edit it

This wouldn't be in the spirit of the [Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) that you agree to release all your posts in.    This states that all users are free to:

> to Remix — to adapt the work
>
> to make commercial use of the work

This feature couldn't really be implemented by Stack Exchange without facilitating a back door in the license - this is partly why moderator locks are quite uncommon against the background of larger sites such as Stack Overflow.